# Multi cluster mesh not working on Istio 1.16

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, mesh, istio, servicemesh

Multi cluster mesh was working just fine with istio 1.3.4.

But after the upgrade to 1.16 it stopped working. I even tried the helloworld sample given to verify the mesh config. But it is not working as expected.

The example i tried : https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/multicluster/multi-primary/

But the response is not getting loadbalanced between 2 clusters. The response is always from 1 where im running the curl.

Except the multicluster mesh, everything else is working fine.

Regards!